# Why can't I add images to Amplify through the figma tookit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, figma

Could you please clarify what I might be overlooking? Every time I attempt to substitute an existing image in the Amplify toolkit on Figma, or when I introduce a new one, I encounter an issue upon synchronization. While it acknowledges the presence of an image, it fails to display the actual picture, leaving me with just a blank placeholder instead.

the image shows up just fine in figma.